# Find the value of $a,b$ so that the function $f$ is continuous for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus

Find the value of $a,b$ so that the function $f$ defined below is continuous for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, where $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\lg(x^2+b^3-2) && x<2\\\lg\left(\dfrac{a}{5}\right)+1 && x=2 && a>0,\ b>\sqrt[3]{2}\\\lg^2(ax) && x>2\end{cases}$$
Note: $\lg x=\log_{10}x$

I think that the only point at which the function can be discontinuous is at $x=2$. Is this so? Why?

For it to be continuous at $x=2$, we need $$\lim_{x\to2^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to2^+}f(x)=f(2)$$ which is $$\lg(b^3+2)=\lg^2(2a)=\lg\left(\dfrac{a}{5}+1\right)$$ I don't see how to solve $$\lg^2(2a)=\lg\left(\dfrac{a}{5}+1\right)$$ Also they wrote $a>0$ for the logarithms to be defined, but what about $b>\sqrt[3]{2}$? Is the reason the same?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean to write $b>-\sqrt[3]2$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, nope, that's exactly how the problem is stated in my book. But I guess the inequality $b>-\sqrt[3]{2}$ comes from the domain of $\lg(b^3+2)$. Maybe it's a technical mistake?

Comment: Edit note; you can use `&` column separator (or `&&` for more spacing) instead of `\quad\quad\quad` which won't align as nicely.

Comment: $\lg(2a)^2=\lg(a/5)+1 \iff  \lg(2a)^2=\lg(a/5)+\lg(10) \\\iff \lg(2a)^2=\lg(2a) \iff \lg(2a) =0 \;\vee \;\lg(2a)=1 \\\iff 2a=1 \; \vee \; 2a=10$

Comment: typo it is $\lg(a/5)+1$ with the $1$ outside the parenthesising, which allows to solve by setting $u=\lg(a)$ the remaining are constant $\lg(5)$ and $\lg(2)$ by multiplication to addition formula. You get a quadratic in $u$.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the function doesn’t match your last equation. Correct would be:
$$\lg^2{2a}=\lg{(\frac a5)}+1=\lg{(\frac a5\cdot 10)}=\lg{2a}\Rightarrow \lg{2a}\in \{0,1\}$$

The reason $a\gt 0$ is so that $\lg{2a}\in \Bbb R$.

The reason $b\gt \sqrt[3]2$ is so that $\lg(x^2+b^3-2) \in \Bbb R\Rightarrow x^2+b^3-2 \gt 0\Rightarrow b^3-2 \gt 0$

If the function was defined such as $f(2)=\lg(\frac a5+1)$ then solving $f(2)=\lim_{x\to 2^+}{f(x)}$ would lead to $a=\frac 59, b^3=8$.